# JAXB Generated Classes by Gradle Dependency Issue

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb

I have a set of gradle build script that uses JAXB to generate Java classes from XSD. I am able to generate the Java classes, however the classes seems to be missing dependencies and will not compile.

### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

configurations {
    jaxb
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

task genJaxb {
  ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated/jaxb"
  outputs.dir sourcesDir

  doLast() {
    project.ant {
      // Create output directories
      mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)

      taskdef name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath

      xjc(destdir: sourcesDir) {
        schema(dir: "${projectDir}/src/main/xsd", includes: '**/*.xsd')
        produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: '**/*.java')
      }
    }
  }
}

build.dependsOn genJaxb

dependencies {
   compile(files(genJaxb.sourcesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
   jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7'
   compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.3'
}
```

When I had the generated file directory into the build path, the classes seem to be missing several dependencies.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
```

I tried adding the missing dependency but I never see it get downloaded.

Comment: i can see those import classes in "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.3". maybe you can change dependency type to "implementation" from "compile" and see if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Comment: @taiyebur I tried your suggestion, but still the same result. The issue is I do not see the jaxbi-api jar in my external dependencies folder.

Comment: you can check this one and see if dependencies download. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485819/gradle-build-doesnt-download-dependencies