# Why isn't Gradle downloading the dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add this [ColorPicker](https://github.com/kristiyanP/colorpicker) to my Android project.

I imported this library into my Java class:

```
import petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker.ColorPicker;
```

When I add it to Gradle and sync, I don't get any error.

But when I build the project, I get this error:

```
Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker-library/1.1.10/colorpicker-library-1.1.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Gradle Project file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

Gradle App file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.appname'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.10'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I have Android Studio version 2021.3.1 Patch 1 installed.

I followed the steps mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485819/gradle-build-doesnt-download-dependencies), but it didn't work.

I am facing the same issue with this [ColorPicker](https://github.com/aziztitu/AndroidPhotoshopColorPicker) too.

Does anyone have any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the library is old and wasn't migrated to the Maven Central repository, since JCenter was deprecated.

But you can use it from [Jitpack repository](https://jitpack.io/#kristiyanP/colorpicker/v1.1.10):

1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2. Add the dependency to your app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.kristiyanP:colorpicker:v1.1.10'
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I tried pulling the library and had same results as yours. Looking at these 3 search results from the maven repository

[Search Result 1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/petrov.kristiyan/colorpicker-library)

[Search Result 2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/petrov.kristiyan/library)

[Search Result 3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker/colorpicker-library)

Looks like the repository hasn't been updated for years, have you considered looking for another color-picker library?, I'd recommend this one that I use.

[Go Daddy Color Picker](https://github.com/godaddy/compose-color-picker)

Not sure though if the developers have an xml version of this, as this is targeted to `Compose` usage, but you can integrate `composables` to xml, and this  picker returns an object that holds 4 properties of a Color, `hue`, `saturation`, `alpha` and `value` that you can use.