# Unresolved reference: kotlinx in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I'm using Eclipse IDE (2023-12) on Linux (JDK home: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`) with Kotlin plugins installed (Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse [latest] + Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.24 [latest]).

Trying to learn coroutines; importing them with

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

fails with error:

```
Unresolved reference: kotlinx
```

searching the web has yielded no results in fixing this issue.

Has anybody else ran into this issue? What would the fix be?

Comment: [The kotlinx.coroutines dependency needs to be added.](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines?tab=readme-ov-file#using-in-your-projects)

Comment: Thanks, @howlger - I've added the required statements in `build.gradle`, however, upon build I'm encountering a bug. Opened [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77920876/could-not-open-cp-init-generic-class-cache-for-initialization-script-in-eclipse) for this.

Comment: Back from [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77920876/could-not-open-cp-init-generic-class-cache-for-initialization-script-in-eclipse) with `build.gradle` in place. I synched gradle and the error still occurs.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485819/gradle-build-doesnt-download-dependencies) solved the issue (had to remove cache from `~/.gradle/`).