# > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC2] on object of type

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to run the following code in Eclipse IDE (Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)) on Linux (JDK home: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`) with Kotlin plugins installed (Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse [latest] + Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.24 [latest]):

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    /** Synchronous code example */
    println("Weather forecast")
    println("Sunny")
    
    println("\n\n--------------------------\n\n")
    
    /** With a delay */
    println("Weather forecast")
    delay(1000)
    println("Sunny")
}
```

with `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC2")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

however, trying to build I'm getting the following exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/${USER}/Development/Kotlin/KotlinFundamentals/Coroutines/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Coroutines'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

CONFIGURE FAILED in 80ms
```

Buildship version:

```
  Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle    3.1.9.v20240116-1515    org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship
```

I'm using Gradle version 8.6-rc-4 as **Specific Gradle version** configuration in Gradle panel under Window > Preferences.

Any hints on how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with the following `build.gradle` configuration:

```
plugins {
    // For build.gradle (Groovy DSL)
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.9.21"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC2")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

it seems that order of statements matter. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77919658/unresolved-reference-kotlinx-in-eclipse-ide) for reference.